# Store loop into array

Tags: php, loop

I am using folowing code to store posts ids into array:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc');
$id = array();
$counter = 1;       
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
    $id[$counter] = get_the_id();
    //custom_shop_array_create($product, $counter);
    $counter++;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

However it doesnt work because if I put `print_r($id)` after endif it only prints id of last post. Where am I making mistake?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$id[$counter] = get_the_id();
```

with

```
array_push( $id, get_the_ID() );
```

to collect the post id's into the `$id` array.

### Update:

If you also use `$ids` instead of `$id`:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc');
$ids = array();
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
       array_push( $ids, get_the_ID() );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: not working. It is still acting like $id is not an array.

Comment: what if you use `$ids` instead of `$id` ?

Comment: working ... there must have been some sort of interference with wordpress variables

Comment: ok great, must have been some interference, you could try var_dump($id) check it before and after.

Answer (score 1):

While @birgire's answer solves the problem, it does not explain it. `$id[$counter] = get_the_id();` should work but in this case triggers a `Warning` that you cannot use a scalar value as an array. Why?

[`the_post` runs `setup_postdata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php#L2863), which sets `$id` to the post ID, overwriting your `$id` and turning it into an integer. You can see that by adding `var_dump` after `the_post()`, like this:

```
$products->the_post();
var_dump($id);
```

Beyond that, your code is overly complex. You don't need the counter (and if you did you already have `$products->current_post`) and you don't need any particular function to push items onto the array. All you really need to do is use a variable that WordPress isn't already using, which is what makes birgire's solution work.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'desc'
);

$ids = array();  
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $products->have_posts() ) : 
    $products->the_post();
    $ids[] = $post->ID;
    //custom_shop_array_create($product, $counter);
  endwhile;
endif;
```